# Motherboard - no video, no usb power

Tags: boot, motherboard

I've moved my PC to a new case today, hurray. But when I completed the assembly, it just won't turn on.

What happens is, the power led lights up, I can hear the HDD working, the fans spin up, and that's it. Nothing, it won't boot, there's no video on the monitor, and no power from the USB ports.

What I've done so far:

- Made sure that all power connectors are in place (24 and 8 pins)
- Reinserted RAM and GPU
- Correctly connected the Power and HDD leds to the motherboard

Any suggestions? PSU should be OK, I'm afraid my mobo is dead :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! I had one extra stand screwed in (the little pins the motherboard lies on), that most likely have caused a short circuit. All is fine now!